# How to model the NoSQL database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I want help with following database development with the use of firestore nosql

[image]

with an RDBMS we can develop the above database tables as follows

```
Customer(**CustomerId**, Name, Address)
Vehicle(**RegistrationNo**, Brand, CustomerId, ownerId)
Owner(**OwnerID**, Name)
```

but I want this in NoSQL. For that, I can create 3 collections as customer, Vehicle, Owner. But how to deal with those primary keys when creating documents in them via firebase firestore in flutter. Can I generate a random ID that is unique and Is it a good idea to name the document Id with the primary key?

```
An example document for vehicle collection

docname{
  RegistratonNo: 'uniqueKey' 
  brand: 'ford'
  customerId: customerId
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In NoSQL, we have Collections and documents
The NoSQL equivalent of your schema is
having three collections

- Customer Collection
- Vehicle Collection
- Customer_Hire_Vehicle Collection

in Customer Collection, every customer will have it's own document,
you can choose to make the document Id the Customer Id, or use an alternative
which  is generating your own customerId

in the Vehicle Collection, each document contains the Registration No,
Brand, and since each vehicle has one owner, owner fields, can just be added
to the Vehicle document

for the Customer_Hire_vehicle collection
you can add all the fields of customer and fields of vehicle and also add hireDate
so you know when a customer hired a vehicle, will also come in handy for sorting.

This approach uses `Denomalization`(simply means duplicating data to reduce or simplify your queries instead of
using complex joins) will have some data consistency issues, but it's very common in
NoSQL you can use Multi-path updates to keep data consistent across documents

Denormalization
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA

Data Consistency with Multi-path Updates
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw

Comment: Is it ok if I set the document ID as the customer ID to uniquely identify the customers? If yes then I can remove the customer ID field from the document because it did similar functionality. Is it make future problems?

Comment: @TechlingdaTutorials yes, it's definitely okay to use document ID as the customer ID, especially since firestore document ID is unique, there won't be future problem. But also if you're using firebase authentication you'll  get a different uid to identify users, you can use that as customer Id if that's the case.